# Unmarshal DynamoDBAttributeValues into a struct with different attributes

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I read some data from dynamodb. This is what I get

```
{
  Item: {
    rating: {
      N: "6"
    },
    pk: {
      S: "artist-1"
    },
    gender: {
      S: "woman"
    },
    sk: {
      S: "Alexandra A"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have a struct which looks like this:

```
type Artist struct {
    ArtistID string  `json:"id"`
    Gender   string  `json:"gender"`
    Name     string  `json:"name"`
    Rating   float64 `json:"rating"`
}
```

Now I do

```
artist := model.Artist{}
err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &artist)
```

Now I can access e.g. gender with `artist.gender`. So this is fine, but I can't do this for ArtistId because it's called pk in my dynamodb and I use 'id' for my struct. What is a clean way to solve this? I don't want to replace my 'id' with 'pk' in the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnmarshalMap()` didn't support any given tag Unmarshal. If you don't want to change 'id' with 'pk' in the struct then you have to set value of `pk` in `id` key before `UnmarshalMap` in map manually.

```
func UnmarshalMap(m map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue, out interface{}) error {
    m["id"] = m["pk"]
    dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(m, out)
}
```

Tt's better to create a own generic Unmarshal function for this special case tweak and then call `UnmarshalMap()` inside.

```
artist := model.Artist{}
err = UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &artist)
```